# FabricJS Canvas - video flickering when setting currentTime

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, html5-video, fabricjs

Whenever I set the current time for a video inside a canvas (Fabricjs) the entire canvas flickers. I have been trying to debug this for quite some time and literally am out of ideas... Would any bright minds care to help? I have created a JSBin to illustrate the issue.
https://jsbin.com/wegehorebe/1/edit?html,js,output

```
Please use the slide and reproduce the issue. Thank you!
```